# Search input field AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, search, input, filter

I want to implement a search-box in AngularJS, but the way of implementing it is unclear for me.

I have a function that filters an array, but I do not know how to compare the filtered array with what I actually have in my array, to match some text.

This is my JS:

```
$scope.selectAll = function(modelItemsList) {
  console.debug("searchText", $scope.searchText);
  filteredArray = filterFilter($rootScope.modelItemsList, $scope.searchText);
  console.log(filteredArray);
  $rootScope.temp = [];
  console.log($scope.modelItemsList);
  $rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected = !$rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected;
  console.log($rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected);
  if ($rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.modelItemsList.length; i++) {
      $rootScope.temp.push($scope.modelItemsList[i].name);
      console.log($scope.modelItemsList[i].name);
      $scope.modelItemsList[i].isChecked = $rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected;
      console.log($scope.modelItemsList[i].isChecked);
      console.log($rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected);

    }

  } else if (!$rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.modelItemsList.length; i++) {
      $scope.modelItemsList[i].isChecked = $rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected;
      $rootScope.temp = [];
      console.log($scope.modelItemsList[i].isChecked);
    }
  }
}
```

This is my html:

```
<!-- /.modal-search-box -->
<div class="md-list">
  <md-checkbox ng-model="modelItemsList.allItemsSelected" ng-change="selectAll(modelItemsList)">
    {{"Alle markieren" | translate}}
  </md-checkbox>
  <md-list>
    <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="modelItem in modelItemsList | filter:searchText track by $index">
      <div class="md-list-item-text">
        <md-checkbox ng-model="modelItem.isChecked " aria-label="Checkbox 1" ng-change="selectModelItem(modelItem)">
          <h3>{{ $eval('modelItem.'+propertyName) }}</h3>
          <p>{{ $eval('modelItem.'+propertyDesc) }}</p>
        </md-checkbox>
      </div>
    </md-list-item>
  </md-list>
  <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="saveValues()">{{"Aktualisieren" | translate}}</md-button>
</div>
```

How can I compare the partial text from the filtered array with what I actually have in my array. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can u please provide a plunkr link